# SEO - how to determine if a link if strong or not?

Tags: seo, google-search, backlinks, link-building

I know most people want links from sites which are PR8 or PR7 and that is sort of the holy grail of SEO.

But it occurred to me that Twitter is a PR-8 site. But if I tweet a link, I don't think it does anything for my SEO. So there must be some way Google distinguishes between different PR7 or PR8 sites.

So how can I know what link might be good, and what link might be less good to get?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: The MOST important thing is to have a natural and relevant link.

Answer (score 6):

People who chase high PR links have no idea what they are doing or talking about. A *long* time ago PageRank was very important and a high PR link meant high rankings. But that hasn't been true in a long time. Google has improved their algorithm tremendously since then and other more important signals, ones that actually make sense, factor into a link's value.

Some of those factors include:

- The content of the linking page (the more closely it matches the content of the linked to page the better)
- The ranking of the page giving the link for the content of the linked page (related to point #1)
- The anchor text of the link
- The text surrounding the link
- With Panda and Penguin you can infer the quality of the overall website is a factor

There's more but that should give you an idea of what Google is looking at and why chasing PR is a waste of time.

(FYI, PageRank is per page, not per site. So Twitter is a not a PR8 website. It's *homepage* has a PR of 8).

Comment: So considering that the link is from a relevant site and page, how do you tell if that link is valuable or not? And how do you determine how valuable it might be?

Comment: You can't. You can guestimate its value but only Google knows exactly how valuable it is.

Comment: so if you don't use PageRank, what factors do you use to "guesstimate?" This was really at the heart of my original question.

Comment: It's impossible to estimate, you should consider all links that come from other trustworthy sites that are relevant to your own.

Comment: The biggest mistakes which i also seen, so many newbie try to put url in commenting.

But biggest problem i facing that my blog has 95% no follow backlinks.
Till now i found that only via Guest post i can get Do follow backlinks, beside that i facing problem how to get do follow links and suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: The harder it is for you to earn the backlink, the more valuable it is.

I agree with John Conde, don't chase high PR links, there are other attributes that make a 'strong' backlink like:

- The content
- The social signals of that page (Google+, Twitter, Facebook, etc)
- The amount of traffic generated from that link (the link is clicked by real people?)
- Is the backlink from a website written in the same language of your site?